# How to upload image to classpath directory in spring boot?

Tags: image, spring-boot, upload

Hi~ I'm junior programmer.. I try to upload image to classpath directly!
but it's error code! I want to setting image directory address in application.yaml. Help me :)

```
## application.yaml

mybatis:
 mapper-locations: classpath:/sqlmap/sqlmapper_*.xml
file:
 upload-dir: **classpath:/static/img** ## error!
 upload-dir: C:\Users\img ## success!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
spring:
  http:
    multipart:
      location: d:/root
```